# Pull email-to-case configuration from scratch org and deploy it through unlocked package

Tags: unlocked-package, email2case

We would like to pull the email-to-case metadata from scratch, save them in our Version Control System and deploy it through unlocked package (changing/removing EmailServicesAddress attribute in our CI pipelines). How can we retrieve the metadata from scratch?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the metadata coverage report [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/51) you cannot package the [CaseSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_casesettings.htm) as a part of the unlocked package!

You can retrieve and deploy though to various orgs using the metadata API though. To retrieve via the metadata API use the below package.xml as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>Case</members>
    <name>Settings</name>
  </types>
<version>50.0</version>
</Package>
```

You can retrieve the settings by creating an `src` folder in your project, have `package.xml` in the root of the src folder with the above contents and use the below command

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -k ./src/package.xml -r ./src --wait=-1 --json
```

And deploy using the below commands

`sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d ./src --wait=-1 --json`